# What to call this building?

Tags: single-word-requests

The government/ society erects a building in memory of or in praise of a person who worked for nation or society. What is that building called?

Answer (score 6):

**[memorial](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=memorial%20definition)**

> mɪˈmɔːrɪəl noun
>
> 1. a statue or structure established to remind people of a person or event.
>      "a memorial to General Robert E. Lee" 
>      synonyms:  monument, shrine, mausoleum, cenotaph;

Note the list of synonyms within the definition.

Comment: +1 because you *didn't* use an image...

Comment: @LamarLatrell - Haha! Yes.

Answer (score 4):

a **memorial** is something designed to preserve the memory of a person, event, etc., as a monument (or a holiday).

> Located in Washington, The Lincoln memorial honors the “Great Emancipator” and 16th President
>   of the United States, Abraham Lincoln. Designed by Henry Bacon in the
>   style of ancient Greek temples, construction began in 1914, with the
>   memorial opening to the public in 1922....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to a ***[monument](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/monument):***

> - a structure, such as a building or sculpture, erected as a memorial.
> - something erected in memory of a person, event, etc., as a building, pillar, or statue.

The Free Dictionary

[image: Monument américain commémoratif de la bataille du Saillant de Saint-Mihiel Montsec]

American commemorative monument for the Battle of Saillant de Saint-Mihiel - Montsec.